# The origin of "Loka samastha sukhino bhavanthu"?

Tags: scripture

Most of us heard this famous quote *"Loka samastha sukhino bhavanthu"* (let everybody live peacefully).

Where it is originated from and which shloka mention this line and from which text ?

Comment: I heard this recited by the poojari at the end of a pooja (Sudarsana Homam)conducted at my residence years ago.Later, I heard some one mentioning in a meeting in a temple that this is the last slogan in Irg veda. But I could not find the same in a copy of the same with me.
However, one thing is sure, that the Irishis of ancient Bharat did their worships and poojas for the well being of the entire universe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This phrase is from one of the ***Mangala Mantra*** often recited after a *pooja* or religious ceremony.

> स्वस्तिप्रजाभ्यः परिपालयंतां न्यायेन मार्गेण महीं महीशाः ।
>
> गोब्राह्मणेभ्यः शुभमस्तु नित्यं **लोकाः समस्ताः सुखिनोभवंतु** ॥
>
> ॐ शान्तिः शान्तिः शान्तिः |

---

> svasti-prajā-bhyaḥ pari-pāla-yaṁtāṁ nyāyena mārgeṇa mahīṁ mahīśāḥ |
>
> go-brāhmaṇebhyaḥ śubham-astu nityaṁ **lokāḥ samastāḥ sukhino-bhavaṁtu** ||
>
> auṁ śāntiḥ śāntiḥ śāntiḥ |

---

Translation

> May the well-being of all people be protected
>   By the powerful and mighty leaders be with law and justice.
>
> May good success be with all cows (divinity) and scholars, **May all (samastah) the worlds (lokha) become (bhavantu) happy (sukhino).**
>
> Om peace, peace, peace

[AshtangaYoga](http://www.ashtangayoga.info/source-texts/mantra/mangala-mantra/)

Comment: Is there any difference between  lokāḥ samastāḥ sukhino-bhavaṁtu and samastāḥ  lokāḥ  sukhino-bhavaṁtu.

Comment: @Ganesh, semantically, IMHO no. Both are identical in meaning.

Answer (score 3):

I had first heard this mantra from the prayer gatherings of [Sathya Sai Baba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sathya_Sai_Baba).

This mantra doesn't seem to have origins in any vedic text but may just be a saying of some wise guru which got orally transmitted. This mantra is considered a [Shanti Mantra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanti_Mantra). There is also a possibility that it existed in some vedic branch which was lost <sup>[1]</sup>.

<sup>[1]</sup> [Reference](http://archives.amritapuri.org/bharat/mantra/lokah.php)

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry.. may be i have to recheck the above.. definitely from vedas the mangala sruthi has started.. which are....
 loka samastha sukhhino bhavanthu on wards..

so i have kind of mixed  it up with Aaditya hridayam.... Somehow I remember both of them being chanted  together .. like at the end of aaditya hridayam.. i remember the loka samastha being chanted.. back in N.Parur  our Vadyar. taught us Aadityahridayam..at the Paandi Samooha madam in the  Sasthamkovil premises.. in the years early 70s ...we were 10 - 15 girls and we were taught to chant Lalitha sahasranamam,Soundariya lahari ,ganesha sthothram( Mudakaratha modakam) ,Aditya hrudayam, and even started with Sivananda lahari..
The boys were taught Vushnu sahasranamam, Syamaka dantakam,Siva kavacham...etc...
We used to play there, learn the sthothram and come back homd after school.. 
Feel so nostalgic.. Uma, Gayathri,.. me, Pushpa,...
Later we were used to be invited to chant these in the Theru houses one after another 
and by the end of the year, both Lalitha sahasranamam and Soundariya lahari we had by-hearted
.. even now remember all of it byheart..
though few years of non chanting has resulted in  forgetting the order of Soundariya lahari versus.
but... .otherwise all versus are. hridistham..Namaskarams to our Guru .. Vadhyar..

Comment: -Welcome To Hinduism SE!  You can anytime make changes or improve your answer by using edit menu provided below the answer section. Feel free to add or remove passages from your answer if you feel to do so and  if you find any mistakes in your answer.Regards

Answer (score 1):

Sai Ram! We can find this from Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lokaksema_(Hindu_prayer)

> *The origin of the Lokaskema, often called the Mangala Mantra, is obscure. While some yoga practitioners and Hindu scholars erroneously point to the Rig Veda or the invocation of the Katha Upanishad, the only written attribution or textual source of "lokah samastah sukhino bhavantu" seems to be stone inscriptions from the Rulers of the Sangama Dynasty (1336 A.D.-1485 A.D.).[1]*

This is the mantra they have been putting, "Svasti Prajabhyah". It is not present in the Valmiki Ramayana, so perhaps it is something that is chanted in addition to the original text, as an addendum.

So it seems that there is no source for the mantra, unlike the Asatoma which is found in some Upanishads.

Hope this helps!

Comment: please try to use non wiki sites, as they are a tertiary source or evidence.